# How to align nav-item to center of page

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.clearfix::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;

    .nav-container {
        padding-right: 2rem;
        padding-left: 2rem;
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
        margin-top: 2rem;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;

        .nav-list {
            list-style-type: none;

            .nav-item {
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 2rem;
                padding-right: 2rem;
                font-size: 1.2rem;

                .nav-link {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #fbfdff;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

header {
    background-color: #313131;
    height: 50rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-container">
      <ul class="nav-list">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT ME</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">PROJECTS</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

How can i align nav-item to center of the nav-container ? Navbar should has transparent background, so i wanted to add position: absolute; style to nav element. Also all nav-item s should appear side by side. That's why i added display: inline-block; style to them.

Comment: your styles are not valid css they look like scss so you need a preprocessor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the width of the `nav` to full width, and then use `text-align: center`.

```css
nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Actually i tried to add text-align: center; but didnt try it with width: 100%. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MehmetGüdük Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

there are so many ways to that but I'll prefer to use flexbox or css grid in
'nav-list'.
here's the example using felxbox:

```
.nav-list {
          display:flex;
          justify-content:center;
          align-items: center; (if want to align vertically as well)
          list-style-type: none;
}
```

it will resolve your problem, copy paste and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

just add this in css and it will be in center

```
.nav-list{
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I tried but didn't work.

Comment: @MehmetGüdük   Try this updated ----------------------------

.nav-list{
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

Answer (score 0):

your styles are not correct css syntax.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.clearfix::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}


    .nav-container {
        padding-right: 2rem;
        padding-left: 2rem;
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
        margin-top: 2rem;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
}
        .nav-list {
            list-style-type: none;
}
            .nav-item {
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 2rem;
                padding-right: 2rem;
                font-size: 1.2rem;
}
                .nav-link {
                    text-decoration: none;

                }
            
header {
    background-color: #313131;
    height: 50rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-container">
      <ul class="nav-list">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT ME</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">PROJECTS</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```